# Unable to send coins from freshly forked monero

Tags: ringct, monero-forks

I have forked Monero, made all the config level changes and start the daemon with v9. All nodes are synced perfectly, but when I try to send coins from `wallet-cli` I am getting the below error:

`Error: not enough outputs for specified ring size = 11:`

There are a total of 100 blocks mined so far and I have balance in my wallet, but am unable to send coins due to the above error.

Anyone please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: What config changes did you make? To create a fork with a fresh chain at v9 consensus, there would be quite a few places to change configuration.

Comment: this is my config file

https://gist.github.com/niyas/61e0dc2f5714fddb2b0a19aed65adc9d

please have a look and let me know if i need to make any changes

Comment: You cannot just change this file to get a fresh chain on v9 consensus. You'd need to change things like the HF block heights also.

Comment: Please stick to one thread.